# bcm2835-aux-uart 3f215040.serial: unable to register 8250 port - -28

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, serial

I've compiled LFS for my RPi3B.

- I've put `BCM43430A1.hcd`, `brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin` and
  `brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt` in `/lib/firmware/brcm/`.
- Copied
  `/usr/src/linux/arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb` to
  `/boot/`
- Copied `/usr/src/linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*` to `/boot/overlays/`
- I've copied `*.dat` and `*.elf` of https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot to `/boot/`

**/boot/cmdline.txt:**

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=btrfs rw rootwait cma=256M@256M elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes
```

**/boot/config.txt:**

```
disable_overscan=1

hdmi_drive=2

dtparam=audio=on

gpu_mem=128

arm_control=0x200

device_tree=bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb

kernel=vmlinuz-4.14.94-v8-g049e03d71027-dirty

dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

avoid_warnings=2

dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

hdmi_force_hotplug=1
enable_uart=1
```

I couldn't get Bluetooth or WiFi working. I see no trace of `brcmfmac` or `BCM43430A1`. in dmesg.

dmesg:
http://tinyurl.com/ydhygymr

Comment: Hi there, do you find a solution to this? Hitting the same problem. Cheers